# StripeConnectionError: Request aborted due to timeout being reached (80000ms)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe checkout feature in my website but I am getting timeout error. I'm not redirected to the success page after successfuly checked out. And I can't restart the app even when restarting mongo & nodemon. Always the same error.
Here is my code

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51MmgxaSBOxjynWemPxtDw5yfdE41SwkrQzwxT41hO19Yv7txGI70mmfjX62Tg9K0Q4ZYhWbDpWCRxqnFxyQG53l800hN7bXPG4');

const Order = require('../models/order.model');
const User = require('../models/user.model');

async function getOrders(req, res) {
  try {
    const orders = await Order.findAllForUser(res.locals.uid);
    res.render('customer/orders/all-orders', {
      orders: orders,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}

async function addOrder(req, res, next) {
  const cart = res.locals.cart;

  let userDocument;
  try {
    userDocument = await User.findById(res.locals.uid);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }

  const order = new Order(cart, userDocument);

  try {
    await order.save();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    return;
  }

  req.session.cart = null;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: cart.items.map(function(item) {
      return  {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: item.product.title
          },
          unit_amount: +item.product.price.toFixed(2) * 100 
        },
        quantity: item.quantity,
      }
    }),
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `http://localhost:3000/orders/success`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/orders/failure`,
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
}

function getSuccess(req, res) {
  res.render('customer/orders/success');
}

function getFailure(req, res) {
  res.render('customer/orders/failure');
}

module.exports = {
  addOrder: addOrder,
  getOrders: getOrders,
  getSuccess: getSuccess,
  getFailure: getFailure
};
```

This is the error I am getting
[image: Timeout Error]

Comment: So you have been redirected to the Stripe Checkout, and can purchase there, but when to redirect back to the success page got timeout? Have you check server log for the success page handler request?